# Is __all__ a shorthand for import?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python package init file can have variable `__all__` that lists the sub packages to be imported when using: `from package import *`

Is this same as writing import sub package name(s) in the init file (instead of `__all__`) ?

I have read article thay says if the **init**.py file in the package directory contains a list named **all**, it is taken to be a list of modules that should be imported when the statement from  import * is encountered.

Comment: `__all__` is intended to list the "exported names" from a module.  it will not trigger imports of sub-packages

Comment: @Anthony - an online articles says - if the __init__.py file in the package directory contains a list named __all__, it is taken to be a list of modules that should be imported when the statement from <package_name> import * is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

`__all__` is more useful for individual sourcefiles than it is for an `__init__.py` file. In such `__init__.py` files, you're usually *already* importing only the variables and functions that you intend to make available from the outside of the package. For example:

```
package foo
+-- __init__.py
+-- bar.py
+-- baz.py
```

---

> `__init__.py`

```
from .bar import *
from .baz import *
```

---

> `bar.py`

```
def some_method(): 
    ...

def other_method():
    ...

def hidden_method():
    ...

class some_class:
    ...

__all__ = ['some_method', 'other_method', 'some_class']
```

---

And then outside of the package,

```
import foo

foo.some_method()  # works
foo.other_method()  # works
foo.hidden_method()  # error
```

Comment: This is a really intuitive answer :)

Comment: Also can you tell me What purpose does __all__ serve in the init file of a package? Same as that in module?

Comment: @variable `__init__.py` is really just like any other python sourcefile, except that it's *implicitly* imported when you would try to import the entire folder. Technically you could write all your code just in a `__init__.py` file, in which case you might want to put an `__all__` variable in it to restrict what someone else would import from it. The same way you would for any other sourcefile. The difference here is that `__init__.py` isn't typically used this way, so `__all__` usually isn't useful in it.

Comment: Ok so __all__ should never have module name within it as it is invalid to do so.

Comment: Foll is an article online which differs from your answer. If the __init__.py file in the package directory contains a list named __all__, it is taken to be a list of modules that should be imported when the statement from <package_name> import * is encountered.